# AWS API Gateway Timeout after ~30 seconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

AWS API Gateway timeout after around 30 seconds. I connected the API gateway to a lambda function that runs far longer than 30 seconds.

So the API response times out after around ~30 seconds and give back something like a timeout response.

How do I solve this problem and get my response back from Lambda?

Thank you.

Comment: Will AWS SDK to call 'invoke()' will work here?

Answer (score 8):

The API Gateway has a maximum integration timeout of 30 seconds ([API Gateway Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html)), so there is nothing you can do to increase it.

What you could do is accept the request, create and ID and put it in a queue.
Then you send an HTTP 202 Message with the request id back to the client.
Now a Lambda function can be triggered from the Queue asynchronously that performs the work.
It later persists the results of the query somewhere under the request id (maybe only for a period of time).
The client can then use the request ID and poll a second API gateway for the status, which is able to return the response once it's present.

Comment: Thanks Maurice. Do you think AWS SDK to call 'invoke()' will work here? Thank you.

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to do - you can start both synchronous as well as asynchronous invocations through the invoke API. A synchronous invoke won't help you with the timeout issue if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Does anyone know if this approach is possible using the serverless framework? I can see that the docs mention asynchronous invocation (here: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions#asynchronous-invocation) but I can't find anything more in the docs about it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do anything about api Gateway timeout, it is having hard limit of 30 seconds.

A Solution for this is to use [alb with aws
lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-alb.html), alb is not having any timeout limit.

Another option is polling based as suggested in previous answer by @Maurice.

Comment: Thanks Pankaj. Do you think AWS SDK to call 'invoke()' will work here? Thank you.

Comment: Pankaj, can you elaborate generally how that would work using AWS SKD 'invoke'? Thank you.

Comment: There is limit of 15 minutes in lambda and we do lambda.invoke from stepfunction it also waits for response from lambda.